# Wordpress Shortcode to get Youtube Channel Views via YouTube API

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, youtube-api

I am Wordpress User and not the Programmer.
I want to create a shortcode in the functions.php to get the total views of any youtube channel.

I use the shortcode and give the channel ID Value. After the shortcode function gives back via YouTube API the current Channel Views of the given Channel ID.

In the YouTube Documentation, I found the following Code:

```
function channelsListById($service, $part, $params) {
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $service->channels->listChannels(
        $part,
        $params
    );

    print_r($response);
}

channelsListById($service,
    'statistics', 
    array('id' => 'UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw'));
}
```

The Response looks like that:

```
/**
 * API response
 */
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/d9WwK8U1FuV6c-shZpzmnYUgGvQ\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Psv3E9LCdk66gkF4HSIYK44crMI\"",
      "id": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "118283693",
        "commentCount": "393",
        "subscriberCount": "1165598",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "4435"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I think, I need to add some code to get the item field "viewCount" Value.

I don´t know if it is possible to do that, but I hope some of you Pros know the solution.

At the End of the Code, I just have to add:

```
add_shortcode( 'channel_views', 'shortcode_title' );
```

Would be amazing, if you could respond with the code I have to invert to the functions.php ;)

If you need more information to be able to respond, just ask me.

Answer (score -2):

Use this plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/youmax-channel-embeds-for-youtube-businesses/

This plugin simply gets all the videos from youtube channel in the grid format.

Comment: This plugin does not do what the OP asks for.